# SQLite: Escaping Special Characters

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a common way within Android to escape all of the characters that aren't allowed in a SQLite database?  For instance, "You\'Me'".  Instead of me figuring out every single character that has isn't allowed and creating a bunch or replace statements.  I'm looking for something like the following.

```
value = SQLite.escapeString(value);
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("name", value);
getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

//Retrieve data
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, "name=?", new String[]{SQLite.escapeString(value)}, null);
value = SQLite.unescapeString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

Is this wishful thinking or is there something out there already that solves this?

**UPDATE**

The code above works but in the situations where you can't use the ? operator you still need some way for escaping all of the characters.  For instance:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
+ KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
+ KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT DEFAULT Misc.);");
```

The `.` in this example will throw an exception along with several other characters.  Is there a common method/way to escape all of these characters?

Comment: which characters aren't allowed?

Comment: That's exactly my point.  :-)

Comment: Why the down vote?  How is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: Typically, only `apostrophes` (**'**) need to be doubled (**''**). You can avoid that by using **bound parameters** (the **?** placeholders) and passing a string array containing the `values` to be replaced (no column names!). The "conversions" will be done by Android.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein  Slashes are another case.  I'm currently using bound parameters as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware of slashes. Well, then you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, me neither until a user started seeing errors.  It just seems like we shouldn't have to guess about all of the possible characters and there is a certain way to do this.

Comment: Weird! Can you tell which errors? No, because typical users don't know anything about programming... ;)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein If you insert the field you won't be able to retrieve the row trying to match the exact string.

Comment: ... fields? like `[This is a field name with spaces]`?

Comment: Use prepared statements dude ;)

Comment: given your code sample, you don't have to escape anything. android does it for you.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL, strings are delimited with `'`single quotes`'`. To use one inside a string, you have to double it.

There are no other characters that need to be escaped in SQL.
(If you're embedding strings in another language, such as Java, you also have to use the escape mechanisms of that language.)

To avoid string formatting problems, you should use parameters instead:

```java
String name = "me";
db.rawQuery("SELECT ... WHERE name = ?", new String[]{ name });
```